# How to scale columns in data.frame by single column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data.frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(bifpar = c(0.5, 0.75, 1.0), sd_distfeed = rep(2,3), sd_nodist = rep(3,3), mean_distfeed = rep(10,3), mean_nodist = rep(20,3))
dat

bifpar sd_distfeed sd_nodist mean_distfeed mean_nodist
1   0.50           2         3            10          20
2   0.75           2         3            10          20
3   1.00           2         3            10          20
```

and I'm using dplyr to scale columns with names containing 'dist' by column mean_nodist:

```
library('tidyverse')

dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("dist")), ~ (. / mean_nodist))

  bifpar sd_distfeed sd_nodist mean_distfeed mean_nodist
1   0.50         0.1      0.15           0.5           1
2   0.75         0.1      0.15           0.5           1
3   1.00         0.1      0.15           0.5           1
```

which works fine, but if I scale by column mean_distfeed the column to the right is not scaled:

```
dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("dist")), ~ (. / mean_distfeed))

bifpar sd_distfeed sd_nodist mean_distfeed mean_nodist
1   0.50         0.2       0.3             1          20
2   0.75         0.2       0.3             1          20
3   1.00         0.2       0.3             1          20
```

How do I scale selected columns by a single column, independent of its position in the data.frame?

I'm using R version 4.0.2 and tidyverse version 1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any relevant documentation, github issue or stackoverflow answer related to this right now (but I have seen it somewhere).

Anyway, the reason is `mutate_at` uses updated value of `mean_distfeed` to divide `mean_nodist`.

For this operation :

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("dist")), ~ (. / mean_distfeed))
```

Take 1st row for example, the calculation happens is as follows -

```
sd_distfeed - 2/10
sd_nodist - 3/10
mean_distfeed - 10/10
```

Notice that `mean_distfeed` value is now updated to 1 because of 10/10. So now for next column what happens is -

```
mean_nodist - 20/1
```

Hence, you get the same value.

The solution is to keep the column to be divided at the last so as to avoid this from happening. However, as others have noted this bug has been fixed in `across`.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah that kind of makes sense, although it's still unexpected

Answer (score 0):

`mutate_at` has been superseded. Try using `mutate(across(...` syntax instead:

```r
dat %>% mutate(across(contains("dist"), ~ . / mean_distfeed))
#>   bifpar sd_distfeed sd_nodist mean_distfeed mean_nodist
#> 1   0.50         0.2       0.3             1           2
#> 2   0.75         0.2       0.3             1           2
#> 3   1.00         0.2       0.3             1           2
```

Comment: Thanks for the working solution. I still find the behavior of `mutate_at` strange, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @VincentH I find it strange also. If you change your call to `matches("dist$")`, then you get the desired effect for the final column, but then the others don't match. I think it's a bug in `mutate_at`, since doing `select(dat, matches("dist"))` selects the correct columns

Comment: @27ϕ9 but they are if you do `matches("dist$")` - in fact that matches one column to the left and one to the right

Answer (score 0):

If I use dplyr's `across` ([link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)) function it works fine.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(bifpar = c(0.5, 0.75, 1.0), sd_distfeed = rep(2,3), sd_nodist = rep(3,3), mean_distfeed = rep(10,3), mean_nodist = rep(20,3))
dat
#>   bifpar sd_distfeed sd_nodist mean_distfeed mean_nodist
#> 1   0.50           2         3            10          20
#> 2   0.75           2         3            10          20
#> 3   1.00           2         3            10          20

dat %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols=contains("dist"), .fns=function(x) x/mean_distfeed))
#>   bifpar sd_distfeed sd_nodist mean_distfeed mean_nodist
#> 1   0.50         0.2       0.3             1           2
#> 2   0.75         0.2       0.3             1           2
#> 3   1.00         0.2       0.3             1           2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>